# What is "var" an abbreviation of?

Tags: directory-structure

In the context of `/var` is that an abbreviation for "variables"?

Or what's the intention behind the naming of this folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml),

> /var contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and
>   files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary
>   files.

So you're almost correct, it's not variables, it's an abbreviation for variable.  Files which have variable, changing data.